# How to catch `Request processing failed` for client param error in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web

I register a `DateTimeFormatterRegistrar` in my class implements `WebMvcConfigurer` like this:

```java
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
    registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
    registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
}
```

In the rest controller, i try to parse client `GET` params to an object:

```
@GetMapping("/api/url/path")
public APIResponse getPersonAttendList(@Valid SampleVO vo){}
```

`SampleVO` include field `LocalDateTime time`. If client offered wrong format of `time` param, the binding will be failed. Server will return 500, and print some log like this:

```
>ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] 175 - Servlet.service() for
servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException
```

My question is, **how to catch this exception, and return 400 to the client**? It seems `ControllerAdvice` is not working.

Comment: Check out the documentatoin https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I tried `ControllerAdvice`，but it not works.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Because I cannot reproduce your issue. Everything works as expected, producing error code 400 https://github.com/stafichuk/stackoverflow-question-60741368

Comment: @DenisStafichuk v2.2.2

Comment: Everything works with Spring Boot 2.2.2 as well. My guess is that the problem is somewhere else in the configuration

Comment: @DenisStafichuk i found the real problem now. thanks for your help~

Comment: Would you care to post an answer?

Comment: Could you share your pom ?

Comment: I'll close this question after bounty. I'm very sorry.

Comment: There is nothing to be sorry about. You can help everyone by posting an answer 

Comment: OK. I just added my answer. I just miss some exception here.

Answer (score 3):

In my project I am using `@RestControllerAdvice` to handle such cases, an example would be,

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyCustomExceptionsHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler({HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    public ResponseEntity handleException(HttpMessageNotReadableException httpMessageNotReadableException) {
         //return the response entity you need here with the correct error
    }
}
```

This is something that is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to catch this with a "try{}, catch(){}, and finally{}". You would try the code and then catch the exception, then return a 400 error to the client.

```java
try {
    //your code
} catch (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e) {
    //Return 400 here
} finally {
    //Other code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I made a mistake here. First, i design to return client all response like

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class APIResponse {
    private Integer status;
    private String msg;
    private Object data;

    @NotNull
    public static APIResponse fromData(Object data) {
        return new APIResponse(0, "", data);
    }

    @NotNull
    public static APIResponse fromError(@NotNull BaseError err) {
        return new APIResponse(err.getStatus(), err.getMsg(), null);
    }

    @NotNull
    public static APIResponse fromError(@NotNull BaseError err, Object data) {
        return new APIResponse(err.getStatus(), err.getMsg(), data);
    }

    @NotNull
    public static APIResponse fromEmpty() {
        return new APIResponse(0, "", null);
    }
}
```

I made a global error catch like this:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ErrorWrapper {

    private String getErrMsg(BindingResult bindingResult) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (FieldError error : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
            stringBuilder.append(error.getDefaultMessage()).append(";");
        }
        String msg = stringBuilder.toString();
        log.debug("valid error:{}", msg);
        return msg;
    }

    /**
     * Bean validation error
     * @see javax.validation.Valid
     * @see org.springframework.validation.Validator
     * @see org.springframework.validation.DataBinder
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public APIResponse paramNotValidHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
        BindingResult bindingResult = e.getBindingResult();
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ParamError(getErrMsg(bindingResult)));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public APIResponse paramBindErrorHandler(BindException e) {
        BindingResult bindingResult = e.getBindingResult();
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ParamError(getErrMsg(bindingResult)));
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    private APIResponse paramConvertErrorHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException e) {
        log.debug("valid error:", e);
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ParamError("argument error:%s", e.getCause().getMessage()));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ServletRequestBindingException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    private APIResponse paramBindErrorHandler(ServletRequestBindingException e) {
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ParamError("param bind error"));
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidPropertyException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public APIResponse invalidProperty(InvalidPropertyException e) {
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ParamError(e.getPropertyName() + " format error"));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(PermissionError.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    private APIResponse permissionErrorHandler(PermissionError e) {
        log.debug("not allowed:", e);
        return APIResponse.fromError(e);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    private APIResponse methodError() {
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ClientError("HTTP Method error"));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    private APIResponse fileTooLarge() {
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ClientError("file is too big"));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestPartException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    private APIResponse badRequest(MissingServletRequestPartException e) {
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ClientError("file not exist"));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageConversionException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    private APIResponse badRequest(HttpMessageConversionException e) {
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ClientError("can't parse"));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)
    private APIResponse clientAbortHandler(ClientAbortException e) {
        return null;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ClientError.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    private APIResponse clientErrorHandler(ClientError e) {
        log.debug("bad request:", e);
        return APIResponse.fromError(e);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ServerError.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    private APIResponse serverErrorHandler(ServerError e) {
        log.error("server error:" + e.getMsg(), e);
        return APIResponse.fromError(e);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    private APIResponse duplicateKeyError(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        log.debug("duplicate source:", e);
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ClientError("db unqiue key error"));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    private APIResponse unknownErrorHandler(Exception e) {
        String tips = "unknown error:";
        if (e.getCause() != null) {
            tips += e.getCause().getMessage();
        } else if (e.getMessage() != null) {
            tips += e.getMessage();
        } else {
            tips += e.toString();
        }
        log.error(tips, e);
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ServerError());
    }
```

So, if no catcher matched above, the last one will return 500.

There are so many exceptions for spring boot, i don't know how to catch them all and return 400 without missing any one.

Comment: you have two methods catching `HttpMessageConversionException` this exception is the parent of the exception that I have given in my answer. This catches bot read and write. My answer catches only read conversion. Handle only what you really need. For the rest better to allow spring do its job

Comment: I noticed that, thank you. What i want here is catch all Exception that return 4xx. But there is no easy way...

Comment: do you mean that you want to handle for all 4xx errors thrown from all controllers in 1 way, 5xx in some other way?
I thought you wanted to handle different exceptions thrown not response status's of those exceptions

Comment: Terran, if you want to catch all 4xx exception then you need to check the HttpClientErrorException class. The exception is thrown when an HTTP 4xx has occurred.

Comment: @SergeyNemchinov i mean exceptions that **should** return 4xx, just like exceptions i listed in `ErrorWrapper`. They don't extend from a common base class. So, no easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Surround this statement(DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar()) in try catch block .

```
try{
    DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all spring's exceptions in your controller advice then you need to catch `Exception.class` and then check the class name of the exception.

```
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.your.package.name")
public class ErrorWrapper {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public APIResponse handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        if (ex.getClass().getCanonicalName().startsWith("org.springframework.")) {
            return APIResponse.fromError(new ClientError(ex.getMessage()));
        }
        return APIResponse.fromError(new ServerError());
    }

}
```